# The default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again

Tags: magento2

Hey everyone i am new to magento and while setting it up i encountered this error . Now tried searching for different solution but none of them worked . The other questions related to this error were started on the 4th position but in my case it started in the second position so i couldn't find something to debug this and solve it. I have used lando for magento installation. so can someone help in here . Thanks
[image]

Comment: Remove generated folder. sudo rm -rf generated;

Comment: tried removing generated folder not working

Comment: rename your etc/env.php file and run 

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

command replace your databasename,username and password keep it same as you had installed.

Comment: did you get a solution

Answer (score 0):

=>>> DELETE env.php file.

After run this command

php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento4" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento4" --db-user="root" --db-password= --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-firstname="admin12" --admin-lastname="user" --admin-email="admin12@example.com" --backend-frontname="admin"

Comment: tried removing env.php not worked , same error occurs because the site is getting this error before checking the database at step 2 , the database will be checked at 4th step

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do:

1. Clean env.php file if exist in app/etc folder.
2. Remove generated folder manually or with command `sudo rm -rf generated`
3. Clean database manually or by using `--cleanup-database` option in setup command.

In case, if it not helped, you can try to use another DB name or try to use composer 1.9 version. Also recommend to use installation command with options:

```
magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=es-host.example.com --elasticsearch-port=9200 --cleanup-database
```